# Parse a text file into multiple variables with fgets in C

Tags: c, linux, fgets

My goal is to create two variables in C from the text file that can be used later in the code. My first variable will be the data from lines 1, 3, 5, 7 and so on. The second variable will be the data from lines 2, 4, 6, and so on.

Main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char buf[500];
    file = fopen("ANTdata.txt", "r");

    if (!file) {
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(buf, 500, file) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", buf);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Example of text file:

```
 0.0002746660
-0.0013733300
-0.0002136290
-0.0002746660
 0.0021362900
-0.0006103680
 0.0006103680
-0.0022583600
-0.0011291800
-0.0005798500
 0.0000000000
-0.0001831100
 0.0000915552
-0.0015259200
```

Comment: You can parse each line read via a variety of mechanisms.  `sscanf()` is a general-purpose one, but for your particular purpose you might also be able to use `strtod()`.  Beyond that, it's not clear to me what exactly the problem is.

Comment: I can read the data from the text file with no problem. My question is how do I create two variables such that variable one contains the data from row 1,3,5,7 and the second variable contains the data from row 2,4,6,8.

Comment: @KyleMarciante Please clarify your question then. Check [**How do I ask a good question?**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm sorry, @KyleMarciante, but there are too many ways to interpret that.  Are you asking how to declare variables?  How to parse text?  How to store values in variables?  Do you need your two variables to jointly hold all the data at once, or is one line's worth at a time sufficient?  If all at once, then do you know in advance how much data there will be, or at least an upper bound on that?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be solved easily with `fscanf()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    double x1[1000], x2[1000];
    int n;

    file = fopen("ANTdata.txt", "r");
    if (!file) {
        return 1;
    }
    for (n = 0; n < 1000 && fscanf(file, "%lf%lf", &x1[n], &x2[n]) == 2; n++)
        continue;

    fclose(file);

    /* arrays x1 and x2 have `n` elements, perform your computations */
    ...

    return 0;
}
```

If you just want to handle 2 lines at a time with a different function, here is a simple solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void my_function(const char *line1, const char *line2) {
    printf("x: %s, y: %s\n", line1, line2);
}

int main() {
    FILE *file;
    char line1[250], line2[250];

    file = fopen("ANTdata.txt", "r");
    if (!file) {
        return 1;
    }
    while (fgets(line1, sizeof line1, file) && fgets(line2, sizeof line2, file)) {
        /* strip the trailing newlines if any */
        line1[strcspn(line1, "\n")] = '\0';
        line2[strcspn(line2, "\n")] = '\0';
        my_function(line1, line2);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple anwser (can be improved) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    FILE * fp;
    fp = fopen("ANTdata.txt", "r");

    char * line;
    char oddLine[100];
    char evenLine[100];

    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

    int i = 0;
    int endOfFile = 1;
    int res = 0;
    size_t len = 0;
    while(endOfFile)
    {
        if(i % 2 == 0){
            res = getline(&line, &len, fp);
            strcpy(evenLine, line);
            printf("even : %s", evenLine);
        }else{
            res = getline(&line, &len, fp);
            strcpy(oddLine, line);
            printf("odd : %s", oddLine);
        }
        if(res == -1)
            endOfFile = 0;
        i++;
    }
    fclose(fp);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is :

```
even : 0.0002746660
odd : -0.0013733300
even : -0.0002136290
odd : -0.0002746660
even :  0.0021362900
odd : -0.0006103680
even :  0.0006103680
odd : -0.0022583600
even : -0.0011291800
odd : -0.0005798500
even :  0.0000000000
odd : -0.0001831100
even :  0.0000915552
odd : -0.0015259200
even : -0.0015259200
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what i needed

Comment: Note that `getline` is POSIX but not ISO/IEC.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtod` to convert a text representation of a floating point value to floating point:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
...
char *chk;
double x = strtod( buf, &chk );
```

`chk` will point to the first character *not* converted - if that character is not whitespace or a string terminator, then your input was not a valid float constant:

```
if ( !isspace( *chk ) && *chk != 0 )
{
  // bad input, handle as appropriate
}
```

If you don't want to bother with error checking (you *know* your input file is good), you can pass `NULL` as the second argument.

How you handle assigning which input to which variable is up to you.  If you want to keep your current loop structure (loop while valid input is read), you'll need a way to keep track of which row you're on, and then decide based on that.  Here's one (somewhat fragile) approach:

```
int xvals[N], yvals[N];

int row = 0, i = 0;
while ( fgets ( buf, sizeof buf, file ) )
{
  if ( ++row % 2 ) // row is odd
    xvals[i] = strtod( buf, NULL ); // error checking omitted for brevity
  else
    yvals[i++] = strtod( buf, NULL ); // advance i after both x and y are read

  ...
}
```